# Disable animation in viewpager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I have viewpager2 and adapter for him that extends FragmentStateAdapter. I want user to go to another page only by clicking on tablayout. I have disabled user input for this viewpager2. But when I click on tab, there is animation of fast swiping between pages. But I want just new fragment to show. Like with FragmentTransaction, but with viewpager2 and tablayout. Does anyone knows ho to do it?

Comment: weird. my viewpager2 animation is so slow. i want it to go faster. didnt set anything else just the default smooth scrolling. problem is, its too smooth that its slow.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use addOnTabSelectedListener like this:

```
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(object : TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener {
        override fun onTabReselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }

        override fun onTabUnselected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
        }

        override fun onTabSelected(tab: TabLayout.Tab?) {
            tab?.position?.let { viewPager?.setCurrentItem(it, false) }
        }

    })
```

You already use

> viewPager.isUserInputEnabled = false

**Note :** setCurrentItem(int item, boolean smoothScroll)

> Set the currently selected page with smooth scroll. If you set smooth
> scroll is false, you don't see the animation

Answer (score 16):

`TabLayoutMediator` is what you need. Just set `smoothScroll` to false.

```
public TabLayoutMediator(
  @NonNull TabLayout tabLayout,
  @NonNull ViewPager2 viewPager,
  boolean autoRefresh,
  boolean smoothScroll,
  @NonNull TabConfigurationStrategy tabConfigurationStrategy)
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayoutMediator

Answer (score 1):

I think `viewpager2.setPageTransformer(null)` might give you what you need

https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2#setpagetransformer

> Note: setting a PageTransformer disables data-set change animations to prevent conflicts between the two animation systems. Setting a null transformer will restore data-set change animations.

Comment: this doesn't work, because `Setting a null transformer will restore data-set change animations.`